# Simple JS Refresh Div Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've found a simple JS script that *should* refresh a div every 1000 milliseconds however it is not working, any help is appreciated.

Here's the script:

```
window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 1000);  
function refreshDiv(){  
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;
}
```

Here's the div:

```
<div id="timer">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:
    <?php
        echo (Pot::getTime(1) * 100) / 120;                                 
    ?>%">
    </div>
</div>
```

The script is within a file called script.js and is loaded at the bottom of the page like so:

```
<script src="/styles/js/script.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance for any responses :-)

Comment: I think it should be setInterval(refreshDiv, 1000); i.e. without the quotes and ()

Comment: I don't get the line, `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;`, are you trying to set the inner html? You need to say `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 'something'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've provided it looks like you're not doing anything with the div when refreshDiv is called. If you are trying to change the text with `innerHTML` it needs to be something like `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 'something'`

This javascript should work:

```
window.setInterval(refreshDiv, 1000);  
function refreshDiv(){  
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 'example';
}
```

Note: using no quotes with just the function name in setInterval like `refreshDiv` instead of `"refreshDiv()"` is the recommended way.

Comment: Ah, this seems to have worked. Do you suggest I simply put the code that should be in the div in the JS script? Or is there a method I can follow to update the div itself, something like this?:
(pseudocode)
`innerHTML = getElementContents("timer");`

Comment: I would put the code somewhere else like you show if there's some logic that needs to take place. @user3288788

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes:

```
window.setInterval(refreshDiv, 1000);
```

`setInterval` expects to get a function, not a string.

Comment: Nah, it works with quotes (assuming you have function brackets, and in this case the OP does).

Comment: I have tried both, neither seem to have any effect, @DaveChen is correct I believe. Thank you.